# We can use google-translate without a Google-key?

Tags: web-services, internationalization, google-translate

I found this code in a couple of websites (http://goo.gl/usUSP):

```
<?php
// Basic request parameters:
// s = source language
// d = destination language
// q = Text to be translated

$s = $_REQUEST['s'];
if(!$s)echo "translate.php?s=en&d=es&q=Hello%20World";
$d = $_REQUEST['d'];
$lang_pair = urlencode($s.'|'.$d);
$q = urlencode($_REQUEST['q']);

// Google's API translator URL
$url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&q=".$q."&langpair=".$lang_pair;

// Make sure to set CURLOPT_REFERER because Google doesn't like if you leave the referrer out
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.yoursite.com/translate.php");
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($body, true);
echo $json['responseData']['translatedText'];
?>
```

Ok basically from what I know, every call using the google translate API must provide a valid key (the user's key).

However from the example code above no key is given and it works! prove: http://juzcode.com/translate.php?s=en&d=es&q=Hello%20World.

I've got 3 questions regarding this issue:

1) How is this even possible? (i'm not very php literate)

2) The limit imposed by Google is 100k characters per Google-key. The example uses no key. So basically I'd have unlimited usage?

3) Does it violate http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/terms.html ? (I've tried to read it, really! But I'm no lawyer, I'd just want to be sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) How is this even possible? (i'm not
>   very php literate)

The is the REST API meant for AJAX based calls, not the automated server based API.

> 2) The limit imposed by Google is 100k
>   characters per Google-key. The example
>   uses no key. So basically I'd have
>   unlimited usage?
>
> 3) Does it violate
>   http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/terms.html
>   ? (I've tried to read it, really! But
>   I'm no lawyer, I'd just want to be
>   sure)

You don't want to do that because:

> The Google Translate API must be used
>   for user-generated translations.
>   Automated or batched queries of any
>   kind are strictly prohibited.

using curl from PHP is considered an automated request. Use the [Rest API](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/using_rest.html) instead. You will need a key.